# Json Record to show

Tags: php, json

```
<?php require_once('Connections/mycon.php'); ?>
<?php

mysql_select_db($database_mycon, $mycon);
$query_Recordset1 = 'SELECT country.name as country, country_Message.name as Message
FROM country, country_Message
WHERE country.id = country_Message.country_id';

//$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1) or die(mysql_error());

$query_Recordset2='select name from country';
$Recordset2=mysql_query($query_Recordset2) or die(mysql_error());
$json_output=array();


$json_countryoutput=array();
while($mainrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2))
{
$json_countryoutput[]=array($mainrow['name']=>$mainrow['name'] );

}


mysql_free_result($Recordset2);


$Recordset2=mysql_query($query_Recordset2) or die(mysql_error());
while($mainrow=mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2))
{

$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1))
{



if(strcmp ( $mainrow['name'] , $row['country'])==0)
{
//echo $row['country'];
$json_output[]=array($mainrow['name']=>$row['Message'] );
```

/

```
/$json_output[]1=array('country'=>$row['country'],'Message'=>$row['Message'] );
}

mysql_free_result($Recordset1);

}
//$json_output=array_merge($json_output, $json_countryoutput);

echo json_encode(array('item'=>$json_output,'country'=>$json_countryoutput));





mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
```

Out Put:

{"item":[{"German":"Hello"},{"German":"guten Morgen"},{"German":"gute Nacht"},{"English":"Hello"},{"English":"good morning"},{"English":"good Night"},{"French":"bonjour"},{"French":"bonne nuit"},{"French":"bonjour"}],"country":[{"German":"German"},{"English":"English"},{"French":"French"}]}

i want to change basically i have different country  and each country i want to display all records:
 {"German":[{"hello"},{"gutton Morgan"}],"English":[{""},{""}],"French":[{""},{""}]  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understood what you try correctly but maybe this might help:

```
$recordSet = mysql_query($queryRecordSet1);
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordSet)) {
  if (isset($results[$row["name"]])) {
    $results[$row["name"]][] = $row["Message"];
  } else {
    $results[$row["name"]] = array($row["Message"]);
  }
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

There can be some syntactical errors but I hope I was able to give you the idea. As the result set will give you something like this:

"German" "hello"

"German" "gutten tag"

When adding them to a result set check if the "German" key is already set or not. If the key exists, then you should just append to the array, if not you should create a new array and add a new element to it.

Comment: $query_Recordset1 = 'SELECT country.name as country, country_Message.name as Message
FROM country, country_Message
WHERE country.id = country_Message.country_id';$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1) or die(mysql_error());

$result=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1))
{

   if(isset($result[$row["country"]]))
   {
   $result[$row["country"]][]=$row["Message"];
   }
   else
   {
   $result[$row["country"]]=array($row["Message"]);
   }


}
echo json_encode($result);



?>

Comment: {"German":["Hello","guten Morgen","gute Nacht"],"English":["Hello","good morning","good Night"],"French":["bonjour","bonne nuit","bonjour"]}